# How to make this kind of constraint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

Let's say have have two tables, A and B.
A contains fields: id, a1, a2.
B contains fields: id, b1, b2.

Asume a one to many relationship from table A to B based on the id field.

Now let's say I want to create a unique constraint on table b that prohibits me from inserting duplicate records based on b1, b2, and a1.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to have a copy of `a1` appear in `B` in order to enforce this as a constraint. If you don't want this visible to your users, you would create a table (say, `_B`) that contains all of `B`s columns + `a1`, and then create a view (with suitable insert triggers to populate `a1`) called `B` that hides this column.

You should also create a superkey of `A` over `id` and `a1`, and use a foreign key constraint (possibly with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`) from `B` over both of these columns to ensure that this copied column correctly matches the corresponding value in `A`.

Whether you then decide that this should be the only foreign key, or continue to maintain the "correct" one (over just `id`) in addition is a matter of taste.

---

E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.A (ID int not null,a1 int not null,a2 int not null,
    constraint PK_A PRIMARY KEY (id),
    constraint UQ_A_a1_check UNIQUE (id,a1)
)
CREATE TABLE dbo._B (ID int not null,a1 int not null,b1 int not null,b2 int not null,
    constraint PK_B PRIMARY KEY (a1,b1,b2),
    constraint FK_B_A FOREIGN KEY (id) references A (id),
    constraint DRI_B_A_a1_check FOREIGN KEY (id,a1) references A (id,a1) on update cascade
)
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.B
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    select id,b1,b2 from dbo._B
GO
CREATE TRIGGER T_B_I on dbo.B instead of insert
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo._B (id,a1,b1,b2)
    SELECT i.id,a.a1,i.b1,i.b2
    FROM
       inserted i
          inner join
       dbo.A a
          on
             i.id = a.id
GO
```

Comment: +1. is the `constraint FK_B_A` needed (after the `DRI_B_A_a1_check` one is added)?

Comment: See third paragraph - as I said, it's a matter of taste. It "documents" the true relationship (whilst the `DRI_` one is hopefully enough clue to the next person that it's there for a DRI purpose rather than to act as a true foreign key)

Comment: Sounds like just adding a1 to table B is going to be a much simpler solution for me then.  Thankfully it's a value that never changes so I should be able to do this without worrying about the header and detail tables getting into an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create a function testing for a duplicate value in table A and add a Check constraint which references the function to table B.